# Unnesting json data

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, recursion

I'm looking to unnest a json object. There are two ways to do this (simplifying things of course) -- one way is to condense the data, and the other way is to repeat the data. Using a very basic example:

```
d = {
    "ID": 12345,
    "Genres": {
      "Genre": [
        {
            "[@FacebookID]": "6003161475030",
            "Value": "Comedy"
        },
        {
            "[@FacebookID]": "6003172932634",
            "Value": "TV-Show"
        }
      ]
    }
```

The first method of **condensing** would do the following:

```
d = {
    "Genres.Genre[@FacebookID]": ["6003161475030", "6003172932634"]
    "Genres.Genre.Value": ["Comedy", "TV-Show"]    
}
```

The second method of **repeating** would do this:

```
d = [{
    "ID": 12345,
    "Genres": {
      "Genre": {
            "[@FacebookID]": "6003161475030",
            "Value": "Comedy"
        }
      }
 },[{
    "ID": 12345,
    "Genres": {
      "Genre": {
            "[@FacebookID]": "6003172932634",
            "Value": "TV-Show"
        }
      }
 }]
```

Given the following json data structure:

```
{
    "Item": {
        "ID": "288917",
        "Main": {
            "Platform": "iTunes",
            "PlatformID": "353736518",
            "Type": "TVEpisode",
            "TVSeriesID": "262603760"
        },
        "Info": {
            "BaseURL": "https://itunes.apple.com/us/tv-season/id353187108?i=353736518",
            "EpisodeNumber": "5"
        },
        "Genres": {
            "Genre": [
                {
                    "[@FacebookID]": "6003161475030",
                    "Value": "Comedy"
                },
                {
                    "[@FacebookID]": "6003172932634",
                    "Value": "TV-Show"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Products": {
            "Product": [
                {
                    "[@Country]": "CA",
                    "URL": "https://itunes.apple.com/ca/tv-season/id353187108?i=353736518",
                    "Offers": {
                        "Offer": [
                            {
                                "[@Type]": "HDBUY",
                                "Price": {
                                    "[@InUSD]": "2.56",
                                    "Value": "3.49"
                                },
                                "Currency": "CAD"
                            },
                            {
                                "[@Type]": "SDBUY",
                                "Price": {
                                    "[@InUSD]": "1.83",
                                    "Value": "2.49"
                                },
                                "Currency": "CAD"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "[@Country]": "FR",
                    "URL": "https://itunes.apple.com/fr/tv-season/id353187108?i=353736518",
                    "Rating": "Tout public",
                    "Offers": {
                        "Offer": [
                            {
                                "[@Type]": "HDBUY",
                                "Price": {
                                    "[@InUSD]": "2.85",
                                    "Value": "2.49"
                                },
                                "Currency": "EUR"
                            },
                            {
                                "[@Type]": "SDBUY",
                                "Price": {
                                    "[@InUSD]": "2.28",
                                    "Value": "1.99"
                                },
                                "Currency": "EUR"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to be able to call a function that condenses or flattens the field based on settings. Here would be an example of the output:

```
# default unnest method is condense
unnest(data, repeated_fields=['Genre', 'Products.Product[@Country]', 'Products.Product.Offers.Offer[@Type]')
```

And the result would be (with the first item explained):

```
# contains four objects instead of one, because we have repeated on
# two fields, each of those having two values.
[{
    "ID": 288917,
    "Main.Platform": "iTunes",
    "Main.PlatformID": "353736518",

    # use default unnest method of condense if not specified
    "Genres.Genre": ["Comedy", "TV-Show"],
    "Genres.Genre[@FacebookID]": ["6003161475030", "6003161475030"],

    # unnest by repeating as it's specified
    "Product.Product[@Country]": "CA"
    "Products.Product.URL": "https://itunes.apple.com/ca/tv-season/id353187108?i=353736518",

    # again, we unnest by repeating since this has been specified
    "Products.Product.Offers.Offer[@Type]": "HDBUY"
    "Products.Product.Offers.Offer.Price": "3.49"
    "Products.Product.Offers.Offer.Currency": "CAD"

},

{
    "ID": 288917,
    "Main.Platform": "iTunes",
    "Main.PlatformID": "353736518",
    "Genres.Genre": ["Comedy", "TV-Show"],
    "Genres.Genre[@FacebookID]": ["6003161475030", "6003161475030"],
    "Product.Product[@Country]": "CA"
    "Products.Product.URL": "https://itunes.apple.com/ca/tv-season/id353187108?i=353736518",
    "Products.Product.Offers.Offer[@Type]": "SDBUY"
    "Products.Product.Offers.Offer.Price": "2.49"
    "Products.Product.Offers.Offer.Currency": "CAD"

},
{
    "ID": 288917,
    "Main.Platform": "iTunes",
    "Main.PlatformID": "353736518",
    "Genres.Genre": ["Comedy", "TV-Show"],
    "Genres.Genre[@FacebookID]": ["6003161475030", "6003161475030"],
    "Product.Product[@Country]": "FR"
    "Products.Product.URL": "https://itunes.apple.com/fr/tv-season/id353187108?i=353736518",
    "Products.Product.Offers.Offer[@Type]": "HDBUY"
    "Products.Product.Offers.Offer.Price": "2.49"
    "Products.Product.Offers.Offer.Currency": "EUR"

},
{
    "ID": 288917,
    "Main.Platform": "iTunes",
    "Main.PlatformID": "353736518",
    "Genres.Genre": ["Comedy", "TV-Show"],
    "Genres.Genre[@FacebookID]": ["6003161475030", "6003161475030"],
    "Product.Product[@Country]": "FR"
    "Products.Product.URL": "https://itunes.apple.com/fr/tv-season/id353187108?i=353736518",
    "Products.Product.Offers.Offer[@Type]": "SDBUY"
    "Products.Product.Offers.Offer.Price": "1.99"
    "Products.Product.Offers.Offer.Currency": "EUR"

}]
```

My approach was to use a bunch of `deepcopy` dicts for each repeated field. Here is an example of what I have so far, which condenses all non-repeated fields.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a help forum. See how to post a [mcve] and [ask] in the [help].

Comment: Worry about the speed once you figure out how to do it at all.  So try to actually solve the problem, and come back if you need help with that.

Comment: Your condensing example is inconsistent, and your repeating example doesn't seem to have any less nesting than the original.

Comment: @ScottHunter the Genre field is a list field (because it's not specified so condensed), but the other fields are single values instead of multiple values. Notice there are four objects instead of one because the number of values of the country (2) x offer (2) = 4.

Comment: @ScottHunter Good Point. I guess I should say “do coding and debugging for you” forum, but that doesn’t sound as good. Any ideas for better names?

Comment: @EthanK thanks for the suggestion here, I've updated the question with the code that I have and noted the particular sticking points that I'm having. I hope now the question is less an "ask for free-form code" and more about a question to a particular issues I'm trying to solve (repeating the structure, etc.)

Comment: @ScottHunter question updated with an example.

Comment: The inconsistency has nothing to do with lists; it has to do with how certain field names get treated.

Comment: @ScottHunter I guess.